# C#: Immutable view of a list's objects?

Tags: c#, immutability

I have a list, and I want to provide read-only access to a collection containing its contents. How can I do this?

Something like:

```
public ICollection<Foo> ImmutableViewOfInventory() {

    IList<Foo> inventory = new List<Foo>();

    inventory.add(new Foo());

    return inventory.ImmutableView();

}
```

Additionally, an immutable `IEnumerable` would also be fine.

**UPDATE:** I realize now that an immutable view of the list would actually be better. (Preserving list ordering semantics.)

This won't give me list behavior, right:

```
    public ReadOnlyCollection<PickUp> InventoryItems()
    {
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<PickUp>(inventory);
    }
```

I'm looking in the documentation but not immediately seeing `ReadOnlyList<T>`.

Comment: Do you want an immutable view of the list, or an immutable view of a set of immutable items from the list?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are wanting an immutable list of the items, you can return a [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) by calling the [AsReadOnly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) method on your list:

```
public IList<Foo> ImmutableViewOfInventory() 
{
    List<Foo> inventory = new List<Foo>();
    inventory.Add(new Foo());
    return inventory.AsReadOnly();
}
```

This returns an implementation of `IList` that is both strongly-typed and not modifiable.

It does *not* however prevent changes to any of the items contained in the list (unless they are value types). To do that, each item must be cloned (deep-cloned if they themselves contain other objects) and added to a new read only list that is returned from your `ImmutableViewOfInventory` method. You will have to implement this yourself unfortunately.

Comment: For some reason I can't `inventory.AsReadOnly()` to compile, even though I've imported `System.Collections.Generic`. It says that the method doesn't exist.

Comment: Actually, that's because I was using an `IList` instead of a `List`. Why isn't it available on `IList`?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at ReadOnlyCollection<T>?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx

Answer (score 0):

new ReadOnlyCollection(inventory);